# What inspired Supernatural's 'The Colt' and Wynonna Earp's 'Peacemaker'?

Tags: supernatural, inspiration

In Reverse Chronological Order:

In Syfy's Wynonna Earp, the main character wields a demon-killing Colt Buntline Special dubbed 'Peacemaker'. [1](http://wynonnaearp.wikia.com/wiki/Peacemaker)

In CW's Supernatural, the main characters and assorted characters wield a supernatural-killing Colt Paterson. [2](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/The_Colt)

It would appear that Wynonna Earp's Peacemaker was inspired by Supernatural's Colt. I'm not going to ask "what inspired The Colt" as that'd be opinion based. Instead, let me be more specific: **What works, movies, stories, myths, or literature may have inspired these *guns* specialized to killing supernatural entities?**

Comment: Probably there are other guns, but that's just an extension on the idea of supernatural killing weapons in general.  The holy sword for the modern age.

Comment: It's rather common trope.

Comment: I've not seen it, but presumably Wynonna Earp would be using a gun made famous by Wyatt Earp, hence the Colt Buntline, correct? Are you asking what inspired the use of a specific model/manufacturer of pistol or what inspired the "demon killing weapon" troupe?

Comment: @JasonK: demon killing weapon trope.

Comment: "I'm not going to ask what inspired X because that would be opinion based, so instead I'm going to ask what may have inspired X and Y." Ignoring for a second that no, that wouldn't be opinion-based if you asked it properly, in an attempt to avoid asking an opinion-based question you've instead asked an open ended list question ("What works involve weapons capable of killing supernatural entities/demons?").

Comment: If you want to know what the inspiration for the Colt was, just ask that. Make it clear that you want an answer sourced from somebody involved with the show, not random speculation, and you've got yourself a perfectly good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Silver Bullet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_bullet) trope for vampires, werewolves, etc goes back to the 1700's and would be a pretty straightforward inspiration. I'm not sure what part of the Colt's ability is inherent to the gun, but a fair amount of its lethality to supernaturals is attributable to its [special bullets](http://supernatural-tv-series.wikia.com/wiki/The_Colt). (The original 13 and then others.)

In the Wiki, it mentions:

> Though it is possible to recreate new bullets for the Colt which work as effectively with the gun against supernaturals as the original thirteen did, it is apparently difficult without the correct help and knowledge. (Sin City)```

where "Sin City" refers to the episode 3.04 in the series.

The Wikipedia link, above, mentions three folkloric sources of things vulnerable to or requiring silver bullets to kill: the Beast of Gévaudan (1760's) was supposedly killed by a silver bullet, Werewolves (English Folk-lore, prior to 1865), and a witch in the Grimm fairytale *The Two Brothers* (1800's), etc. Vampires are famously (though controversially) vulnerable to silver and appear in a whole host of franchises, including *Blade* using silver weapons and projectiles.

Comment: That is a fair point, especially since The Colt's ability was attributed to its bullets on numerous occasions; but, may you provide examples?

Comment: Examples in-show or examples in folklore? I've added a link to a _Supernatural_ Wiki that talks about the gun and the bullets, if that helps.

Comment: Ah. I wasn't specific. Care to provide examples of silver bullet tropes that may have inspired The Colt?